# Swift Delegate without prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm new to `swift` and `ios` development. I have two classes and want them to connect. I'm not using the `prepareForSegue`. This is what I have, something must be wrong somewhere.

```
protocol TimeDelegate{
 func timerDidFinish()
}


class Timer: UIViewController {

// this is where we declare our protocol
var delegate:TimeDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func timeFired(sender: UIButton){

    delegate?.timerDidFinish()

}

}


import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, TimeDelegate {

var timer:Timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func timerDidFinish(){

    println("Delegate is working")
}

}
```

For some reason, **timerDidFinish** is not firing.

Comment: You never give delegate a value.

Comment: @Arbitur Thanks, i did timer.delegate = self, but stil didn't fire.

Comment: delegate?.timerDidFinish() here delegate is nil ? Check this.

Comment: How are you presenting the Timer view controller?  The instance you are presenting almost certainly isn't the one you are allocating and assigning to the property.  You probably need to set the delegate in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: You should not be assigning the delegate to self - it must be assigned to the `ViewController` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your explanation i gather that the two UIViewControllers are not linked in any way.

When you click the button to fire the `@IBAction func timeFired(sender: UIButton){..}` function, you will be in `Timer` UIViewController.

Then when are you instantiating `ViewController` ? Without instantiating it the delegate will never be set.

If you just want to call the `timerDidFinish()` func and want nothing else to do with `ViewController` then do this:

```
class Timer: UIViewController {

var delegate:TimeDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
var vc = ViewController()
self.delegate = vc

}
```

Then your function will be called.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions. Thanks @Raja Vikaram it works now